# How to create a foreign key set for each file in a list of files with django

Tags: python, django, view, model

I'm trying to upload multiple images to my database with Django. I would like each file to be stored separately as a foreign key to the main product. So basically what I mean is that there will be products and then each product will have multiple foreign keys that are images. Django isn't storing the images to the database at all. Here's my code:

```
class product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('', max_length=100,  db_index=True)
    price = models.CharField('', max_length=100,  db_index=True)
    description = models.CharField('', max_length=100,  db_index=True)

class productimage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_images = models.FileField(blank=True)

if request.method == "POST":
    title = request.POST.get("title")
    price = request.POST.get("price")
    description = request.POST.get("description")
    products = product(title=title,description=description,price=price)
    products.save()
    for image in request.FILES.getlist("images"):
        product_images = image
        products.productimage_set.create(product_images = product_images)
    return render(request,'selling/addproduct.html')
```

So basically I would like each product to have a list of images stored as a foreign key to the main product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused - using the `_set` suffix is for *getting* a list of foreignkeys through reverse traversal. To *create* them, you can just create each `productimage` **one at a time**, and then get them using `_set`.

Example:

```
...
for image in request.FILES.getlist("images"):
    productimage.objects.create(product=product, product_images=image)
...
```

and then to get the images through a `product` instance:

```
product.product_images_set.all()
```

Comment: It's still not adding the images to the database

Comment: Did you make sure to add `enctype=“multipart/form-data”` into your form tag?

Comment: Turns out I forgot to add that. Thanks!